# wxPython 4.1.0 GridStringTable.GetAttrProvider

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

So I am in the process of trying to update a code base that had been using wxPython 4.0.7post2 to version 4.1.0.  Lots of problems...

This one, I am not sure if it is a bug in 4.1.0, or if there is a new way of handling things that I am simply not aware of, so wanted to ask the hivemind.

In our code we have a custom wx.grid.Grid, so something like:

```
class OurGrid(wx.grid.Grid):

    def __init__(self,stuff):
        self.CreateGrid(rows,cols, wx.grid.Grid.GridSelectRows)

    def someLaterFunction(self,stuff):
         provider    = self.GetTable().GetAttrProvider()
```

In both 4.0.7post2 and 4.1.0 the GetTable() function returns a wx._grid.GridStringTable, but in 4.1.0 it no longer has the GetAttrProvder function. In fact it seems to be missing a bunch of stuff, mostly things that look like the live on wx.grid.GridTableBase:

4.0.7post2:

```
 ['AppendCols', 'AppendRows', 'AttrProvider', 'CanGetValueAs', 'CanHaveAttributes', 'CanSetValueAs', 'ClassInfo', 'ClassName', 'Clear', 'ColsCount', 'DeleteCols', 'Dele
teRows', 'Destroy', 'GetAttr', 'GetAttrProvider', 'GetClassInfo', 'GetClassName', 'GetColLabelValue', 'GetColsCount', 'GetNumberCols', 'GetNumberRows', 'GetRefData', 'GetRowLabelValue', 'GetRowsCount', 'GetTypeN
ame', 'GetValue', 'GetValueAsBool', 'GetValueAsDouble', 'GetValueAsLong', 'GetView', 'InsertCols', 'InsertRows', 'IsEmpty', 'IsEmptyCell', 'IsSameAs', 'NumberCols', 'NumberRows', 'Ref', 'RefData', 'RowsCount', '
SetAttr', 'SetAttrProvider', 'SetColAttr', 'SetColLabelValue', 'SetRefData', 'SetRowAttr', 'SetRowLabelValue', 'SetValue', 'SetValueAsBool', 'SetValueAsDouble', 'SetValueAsLong', 'SetView', 'UnRef', 'UnShare', '
View', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__',
 '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

4.1.0:

```
 ['AppendCols', 'AppendRows', 'Clear', 'CornerLabelValue', 'DeleteCols', 'DeleteRows', 'GetColLabelValue', 'GetCornerLabelValue', 'GetNumberCols', 'GetNumberRows', 'Get
RowLabelValue', 'GetValue', 'InsertCols', 'InsertRows', 'NumberCols', 'NumberRows', 'SetColLabelValue', 'SetCornerLabelValue', 'SetRowLabelValue', 'SetValue', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '
__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__rep
r__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

The current documentation does not seem to go over how wx.grid.GridStringTable and wx.grid.GridTableBase should relate to each other. Simply telling the OurGrid to use GridTableBase does not work since it is too abstract.

Thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the default is `GridStringTable` you need to subclass `GridTableBase` see `GridHugeTable.py` in the 4.1.0 demos https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/4.1.0/wxPython-demo-4.1.0.tar.gz

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten about the demos.

What I am running into that is confusing, in 4.0.7, GridStringTable was a subclass of GridTableBase, so the default case got all of the GridTableBase functionality.

Now the classes can not be mixed, so one can not even create a subclass of both of them and get the functionality back.